# Addition of ADO.NET entity data model in .NET Core project

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-7.0

While trying to add an ADO.NET Entity Data model in .NET Core project, I'm getting this error :

[image]

I am using latest version .NET Core 7.0 - please can anyone help me resolve this error?

I need to resolve this error regarding adding an ADO.NET ENTITY DATA MODEL

Comment: Which version of **Entity Framework** (or Entity Framework **Core**) are you using? The EF Core versions **do NOT** support ADO.NET Entity Data Models anymore.

Comment: Please post your csproj content with Package References and versions.